# SSRS: How can I use a Search parameter with multiple values?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am creating a report that the business would like to use to spot check 5, 10 or 20 records at a time.

The request was to use a Search parameter (as opposed to dropdown params).

How can I create a Search parameter that will allow for multiple values separated by a comma?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

***Don't worry*** about the length of this answer, most of it is a cut/paste job ! I've tried to explain each bit as we go so you understand it better, the actual amount of code you need to craft is minimal.

If you have SQL Server 2016 then you can take advantage of the new `string_split` function, if you have an older version you'll have to create a similar function yourself, or copy the one I created a few years back which does a similar thing.

Lets get the function created first: I've created it in the `fn` schema but you can obviously change this to whatever schema you like.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [fn].[Split](@sText varchar(8000), @sDelim varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @retArray TABLE (idx smallint Primary Key, value varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @idx smallint,
    @value varchar(8000),
    @bcontinue bit,
    @iStrike smallint,
    @iDelimlength tinyint
IF @sDelim = 'Space'
    BEGIN
    SET @sDelim = ' '
    END
SET @idx = 0
SET @sText = LTrim(RTrim(@sText))
SET @iDelimlength = DATALENGTH(@sDelim)
SET @bcontinue = 1
IF NOT ((@iDelimlength = 0) or (@sDelim = 'Empty'))
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue = 1
        BEGIN
--If you can find the delimiter in the text, retrieve the first element and
--insert it with its index into the return table.

        IF CHARINDEX(@sDelim, @sText)>0
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1, CHARINDEX(@sDelim,@sText)-1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END

--Trim the element and its delimiter from the front of the string.
            --Increment the index and loop.
SET @iStrike = DATALENGTH(@value) + @iDelimlength
            SET @idx = @idx + 1
            SET @sText = LTrim(Right(@sText,DATALENGTH(@sText) - @iStrike))

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
--If you can't find the delimiter in the text, @sText is the last value in
--@retArray.
 SET @value = @sText
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            --Exit the WHILE loop.
SET @bcontinue = 0
            END
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue=1
        BEGIN
        --If the delimiter is an empty string, check for remaining text
        --instead of a delimiter. Insert the first character into the
        --retArray table. Trim the character from the front of the string.
--Increment the index and loop.
        IF DATALENGTH(@sText)>1
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1,1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            SET @idx = @idx+1
            SET @sText = SUBSTRING(@sText,2,DATALENGTH(@sText)-1)

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            --One character remains.
            --Insert the character, and exit the WHILE loop.
            INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
            VALUES (@idx, @sText)
            SET @bcontinue = 0  
            END
    END
END
RETURN
END
```

Once the function is created you can see what it outputs by doing something like

```
select * from fn.Split('Austria, Belgium, France', ',')
```

This returns the following

```
idx value
0   Austria
1   Belgium
2   France
```

Lets assume we have a geography table with the names of countries and their associated region, we can search for matching entries by simply joining to the output of the function something like this.

```
select g.CountryID, g.CountryDesc, g.ContinentDesc from dim.Geography g
    join (SELECT * FROM fn.Split('Austria, Belgium, France', ',')) s 
        on g.CountryDesc = s.value
```

This, in my case, give me this output.

```
CountryID   CountryDesc ContinentDesc
21  Austria West Europe
28  Belgium West Europe
89  France  West Europe
```

To use the split function in your SSRS dataset, simply pass in the search text parameter so the query would now look something like this.

```
select g.CountryID, g.CountryDesc, g.ContinentDesc from dim.Geography g
    join (SELECT * FROM fn.Split(@MySearchText, ',')) s 
        on g.CountryDesc = s.value
```

Comment: Outstanding answer, Alan.

I'm working in SQL Server 2012 but I get this idea and can proceed.  Thank you, Sir.

Comment: Glad to help. If you are using SQL2012 then you will just have to create the function, feel free to use the one I provided. Shame it took MS so many years to include it in their product. If this answers your question would you be so kind to as to mark it as an accepted answer. Regards, Al.